# gulp-clean and del does not work to clean the folder i want

Tags: gulp, del, gulp-clean

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. I want to clean up my `dist/browser` folder, but absolutely noothing happens, not even an error.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const gulpElm  = require('gulp-elm');
const clean = require('gulp-clean');
const del = require('del');

gulp.task("clean-dist/browser-folder", () => {

  console.log("this gets logged - and nothing happens.");

  return gulp.src('dist/**', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean({force: true}));
});

// i commented this out but this 2 aproaches below using del module also don't work

// gulp.task("clean-dist/browser-folder", () => {
//   return del([ "dist/browser"], {force:true});
// });

// gulp.task("clean-dist/browser-folder", async () => {
//   return await del([ "dist/browser/**", "!dist/browser" ], {force:true});
// });
//

gulp.task("default", [ "clean-dist/browser-folder" ]);
```

Also i used `function (){}` instead of `lambda`. Exact same result. WTCrap is happening?
All questions i reaserched plus the docs suggest i'm doing things correctly.

Am i missing something very obvious - i'm just blinded to it right now ? Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Crap! i found it. So basically my `gulp scripts` are in a `gulp folder` like so (sorry i forgot to mention this in the question - since i wasn't thinking is somehow relevant) :

```
rootOfProject/gulp/firstGulpScript.js
rootOfProject/gulp/secondGulpScript.js

// and the cleaning path:

rootOfProject/dist/browser/crap.js
```

I need multiple gulp script files since is a project with multiple apps which require separate compilation in separate locations and such. Seemed nicer to split each app in it's own gulp file. Thinking back at this it might not have been the brightest idea.

Now what happens, in my **clean() task** to delete `crap.js` i have :

`return del([ "dist/browser/crap.js"], { force : true });`

But gulp looks into:

`rootOfProject/gulp/dist/browser/crap.js` - which of course is wrong location.

I am supposed to write this instead:

`return del([ "../dist/browser/crap.js"], { force : true });` - note the `../` in front of the path here. As such the new location will be:

`rootOfProject/dist/browser/crap.js` - which is the correct location to start cleaning.

**There was nothing to clean in `rootOfProject/gulp/dist ..` that's why i wasn't getting any errors. The task was running just fine, but nothing was beeing deleted form dist/... With no errors things were even more confusing**

This hole mess lost me 2-3 hours..

Hopefully if somebody finds an issue like this they will be **more careful about the path specified - when the gulp script file is not in the root of the project**.